# Lines between point and sphere surface intersecting a plane

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, spheres

So, I am looking at an issue that I feel should be pretty easy but I am getting tripped up on. Just looking for some advice on where to start.

I have a sphere that is intersected by a plane and then some point within the sphere that generates 'rays' these rays go from the point to the surface of the sphere and some of which intersect the plane. I am trying to find an equation that helps me find out where the lines intersect the plane.

An image showing what I am talking about is below:
[image]

I am trying to figure out some function of theta and phi that finds the intersection point of these rays given that the radius etc of the sphere is known and the point of ray origin is known.

Comment: Why do you need the sphere? There is a point somewhere, the rays are emitted and there is the plane.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. Do you want an expression for the coordinates of a point on the plane, given the coordinates of a point on the sphere and the point of origin?

Comment: In homogeneous coordinates, if $\mathbf p$ and $\mathbf q$ are the two points and the plane is $\mathbf\pi$, then the intersection is $(\mathbf q^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf p-(\mathbf p^T\mathbf\pi)\mathbf q$.

Comment: @zoli, I am trying to map the coordinates to the plane, so the rays being projected out are from a projector and the plane is a fisheye lens.